# How do you add intellisense for properties on inherited VueJS components in VSCode?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vuejs2, jsdoc

Using VueJS 2 (javascript), I'm trying to add better intellisense in VSCode.

I can use JSDoc syntax to add type definitions within a component, but don't know how to access those definitions from other components.

In the simplified example below, I have a **Base Component** with the `getIsLoaded` and `getSetIsLoaded` **computed properties**.

Below that, is the **Derived Component** which `extends: BaseComponent`.

I want to make VSCode aware of `getSetIsLoaded` and `getIsLoaded`, so that another developer can just type 'this.g' to get a list of the available properties and their types.

### BaseComponent.vue

```
...
<script>
export default {
  name: 'BaseComponent',
  props: {
    isLoading: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
  },},
  data: () => ({
    _isLoading: false, // this is intended to be private
  }),
  computed:
    /** @returns {boolean} */
    getIsLoading () {
      return this.$data._isLoading;
    },
    getSetIsLoading: {
      /** @returns {boolean} */
      get () {
        return this.$data._isLoading;
      },
      /** @param {boolean} val emits update:isLoading, val */
      set (val) {
        this.$data._isLoading = val;
        this.$emit('update:isLoading', val);
  },},},
  watch: {
    isLoading: {
      immediate: true,
      handler (val) {
        this.getSetIsLoading = val;
  },},},};
</script>
...
```

### DerivedComponent.vue

```
...
<script>
import BaseComponent from './BaseComponent.vue';

export default {
  name: 'DerivedComponent',
  extends: BaseComponent,
  computed: {
    valueBundle() {
      return {
        isLoading: this.getSetIsLoading
  };},},};
</script>

...
```

I've tried a bunch of things to get this working but I'm getting nowhere.  If anyone can help me with this, I'd truly appreciate it :-)

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am trying to figure out the same thing right now :(

Comment: @carestad I couldn't figure it out, no :-/